# Contact book software for marketing purposes

Tags: software-recommendation, contacts

I need to organize my lists of work contacts and I can't find a suitable software for the purpose.

My needs are (a) it has to run offline on my desktop PC, (b) allows me to perform searches across all the contacts, (c) light, no-hassle GUI.

Do you know a program which can do the trick?

Comment: export as `.csv` and use LibreOffice Calc or equivalent? ;-)

Comment: Cheers @Rmano, that's probably what I'll end up doing. I was just hoping to find a nice piece of software that would help me organizing the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few suggestions:

- [KAddressBook](http://www.kde.org/applications/office/kaddressbook/)
- [Osmo](http://clayo.org/osmo/)
- [Rubrica](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rubrica.berlios/)

Comment: KAddressBook is a actually a component in Kontact. So I think Kontact should be removed from this list (Kontact is PIM).